# ng-class doesn't set image-background after rendering

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm looking to set the background image of a div dynamically using ng-style. There are a couple of answers, but none work for me.
I've realised that for a simple case as shown below, there's no problem

```
<li ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ image.source }})'}">...</li>
```

where `$scope.image = ...` is defined. Or even more straightforward:

```
<li ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://example.com/image.png)'}">...</li>
```

But supposing you have the following:

```
<li ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ item.image_url }})'}">...</li>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.item = undefined;
Items.get({id: 1})
    .then(function (item) {
        $scope.item = item;
    });
```

Item becomes available after the template has been rendered. And I find that angular just sets the background-image to the host url

```
<li ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ item.image_url }})'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/);">
</li>
```

I could use a custom directive for this, but if there's a simple way of getting this to work, I'd prefer this over a directive.

Here's a plunker demonstrating the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5JsK4njQi7Kc3ShUtRIw?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-style already binds the scope variables, so you don't need to add the curly braces, but could simply concat the correct string value:

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + item.image_url + ')' }"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/b9htGOTY6LBeHQMQNYXV?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{item.image_url}})' }"
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EnZ4oCGlT8E5ILGFcEMI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-if="item.image_url" class="img-div" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{item.image_url}})' }"></div>
```

Use ng-if so when item.image_url get value after that your element is get rendered.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EnZ4oCGlT8E5ILGFcEMI?p=preview)